# How do I *really* disable autocorrection?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid-2, text-editor, auto-correct

I am experiencing this on a Droid2 Global running Froyo, but it was happening on a Droid Pro as well. It did not happen on my Droid running Cyanogen or stock Froyo.

When I'm typing in the gTalk app or using Tweetcaster, my text is auto-corrected. Even when I have auto-correct turned off in the keyboard settings. I use a lot of shorthand, and this gives rise to interesting conversations some times as auto-correct turns abbreviations like "DX" and "D2" into "PD" and similar silliness.

So, the question is: Is there more than one setting for auto-correct? If so, where is it hidden.

*It seems to be global since more than one app suffers from it.*

Comment: there are at least 4 autocorrection-related settings in the stock Froyo keyboard (Auto-capitalization, Quick fixes, Show suggestions, and Auto-complete). If you're using alternative keyboards (or your phone comes with alternative keyboard), then you need to disable autocorrect in those keyboards instead of in the stock keyboard's setting.

Comment: Gingerbread seems to have different options now and seems to suffer from this a little less. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Android 2.2 Froyo Users Manual](http://db.tt/0zpsXLvh), specifically on pages 329 and 330, is mentioned the following settings about auto correction features:

**To access:**

Press "Home" > Press "Menu" > Touch Settings.

## Android Keyboard settings screen

The Android Keyboard settings apply to the onscreen keyboard that is included with
your phone. The correction and capitalization features affect only the English version
of the keyboard.

- Auto-capitalization

  > Check to have the onscreen keyboard automatically capitalize the first letter of the first word after a period, the first word in a text field, and each word in name fields.
- Quick fixes

  > Check to automatically correct some common misspellings as you type.
- Show suggestions

  > Check to show suggested words in a strip above the onscreen keyboard as you type. See “Using the onscreen keyboard” on page 29.
- Auto-complete

  > Check to automatically enter a suggested word, highlighted in orange in the strip above the keyboard, when you enter a space or punctuation. See “Using the onscreen keyboard” on page 29.

## Device Keyboard settings screen

This settings screen is available only if your phone has a physical keyboard.

- Auto-replace

  > Check to correct misspelled words as you type.
- Auto-cap

  > Check to capitalize the first letter of the first word in sentences.
- Auto-punctuate

  > Check to insert a period ( . ) when you press the Space key twice in a row

---

Depending on what exactly you wish to disable, you need to analyse all the above options to match your criteria.